# Alternative For aes_decrypt(unhex()) in MS-SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-migration

I am using encryption and decryption is it working fine in mysql server. i will got the data from mysql server to sql server. i need to do aes_decrypt in sql server. there is any equivalent way for do this in sql server

MySql Query:

```
set @@session.block_encryption_mode = 'aes-256-cbc';
set @Key=X'a42fa5358137948a639eecac4f25f153d25f09375338c17ce6dbd79e085f0e09';
set @IV=X'0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000';
Select convert(aes_decrypt(unhex('efbb757c2834b19e874ee75ac102f6c3'), @Key, @IV ) using  utf8) as FIRST_NAME;
```

Output:

```
FIRST_NAME
------------
Default
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: there are a few ways to do it including built in, asymmetric keys, symmetric keys, certificates, etc. If you want to be able to move the database from one server to another that becomes more limited but you would create a database certificate with a password then generate your asymmetric key and go from there.  There is also pass through encryption which can encrypt entire tables and more.  I recommend searching a little ECRYPTBYKEY DECRYPTBYKEY are 2 functions you will likely use

Comment: No actually i will get the data from the mysql server to sql server so i need to do decryption in mssqlserver

Comment: Forgive me if I don't know that much about encryption in mysql but in order to decrypt the value in sql server you will have to have encrypted it in sql server.  Which means you will have to migrate the data unencrypted from mysql to sql. sql server encryption is not the same as the key iv you are used to. You could try to create a clr in sql server, which I have done using key and iv, but I still would not bet that would work for you. but I am one opinion and these are comments lets see what responses you get.